# How can I transfer contentiously updated data without overloading my server?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have MySQL as DB, JavaScript as frontend tool and PHP for a backend.

I want to build some sort of statistics mechanism for a website, so I would grab the data from the frontend, store it and then be able to output it.

The only way I know to do it, is by sending each time AJAX request when something is clicked/hovered/focused/selected... (etc) and then store it in DB.

My questions are:

1. How can I do it without overloading a server with a bunch of AJAX requests?
2. Is there any way to send(and be actually sent and stored) only when the user is closed the tab/browser...(any action that will fire when a user is off), so I could send one AJAX call with the object(data) collected?

If you have any ideas how it should be done(even if it's with other technologies such as Node.js etc)

Comment: I would recommend you look into using websockets. With `ajax` you will need to continue to call the server to check for updates but with websockets you make one call and keep it open which then binds events to wait for changes/posts rather than having to continuously check.

Comment: Thanks, I will diffidently check it out.

Comment: What "statistics" are you trying to collect and send to server? All user actions?

Comment: Yes, almost all user actions.

Comment: I basiclly thought to build an JS object with all the user actions and then transfer it.

Comment: Not sure what the issue is?

Comment: @guest271314 I think the issue is many actions take place which mean executing many `ajax` calls to the server, hence my suggestion to use websockets.